# CoreBluetooth: CBCharacteristic/service -> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

In an `iOS` app using `CoreBluetooth`, I have an an array (named characArray) containing objects of type `CBCharacteristic`.

When an element is added to the array with:

```
characArray.append(element)
```

I check the element using:

```
print("element.service = \(element.service)")
print("element.service.uuid = \(element.service.uuid)")
```

I never see a problem up to this point.

Inside the code I also have this loop:

```
for x in characArray {
    print("x.service = \(x.service)")
    print("x.service.uuid = \(x.service.uuid)")
}
```

It runs usually fine, but in some cases it crashes.

When using the debugger to see closely what is happening.

The x variables appears fine but x.service (and also x.service.uuid) produce the error message:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1923456...).
```

It does not even happen that x.service is nil, therefore testing (x.service != nil) is not an option. So the question is: *how can I control the flow and see that I should not execute:*

```
print("x.service = \(x.service)")
```

It sounds like the x variable has been lost (deallocated?) at some point. Is there a convenient way to check where?

Comment: Please check if you are not deallocating the x somewhere before the above two lines. It will also be helpful if you can share more code regarding the use of object.

Comment: Can you please share more code? What is the flow related to BLE peripheral  connection and reading of services and characteristics?

Comment: I have updated the post to be clearer. It is not easy to extract the relevant parts of the code and post them.

Comment: I also noticed that it happens when the peer service has gone out of reach, for example the peripheral side application being stopped.